# rpy2 importr failing with errors

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rpy2

Here is my code and setup; (Python3)

```
import rpy2

print(rpy2.__version__)

##  The system replies
3.3.3

import rpy2.robjects as ro

print(ro.r("version"))

## The system replies with
...
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again    

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

datasets = importr("datasets")

mtcars = datasets('mtcars')['mtcars']

## The error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-0763eb983987> in <module>
----> 1 mtcars = datasets('mtcars')['mtcars']
      2 
      3 #datasets()

TypeError: 'InstalledSTPackage' object is not callable
```

I am not sure what's wrong above (in some versions of rpy2 and R, data API is available), I see lots of examples. Is there an issue with the 3.3.3 (rpy2) and R (4.0.2)?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found out the answer.

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data ## data is added

datasets = importr("datasets")

mtcars = data(datasets).fetch('mtcars')['mtcars'] ## changed here

It appears that the API may have changed somewhere.

Comment: It did change a while back now (version 2.4 https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/changes.html#id85)